Confusion about Derivation for Bragg's Law/Condition
I am currently learning about Bragg's Law and its derivation. However, the assumptions/logic behind the derivation seems flawed to me. It is probably likely that I am incorrectly understanding some of the assumptions behind Bragg's Law. Here are areas where I'm confused.

My understanding is that incident X-rays are diffracted by atoms on each layer. If that is the case, why do most drawings depict the incident ray as being reflected?

I understand that for constructive interference to occur, two waves must meet in phase, meaning that one wave must travel n*lambda more distance than the other wave. However, the Bragg's Law derivations I've seen do not account for the fact that the two waves that interfere can leave the plane at different angle. The derivation only accounts for the difference in distance traveled due to one wave penetrating farther into the crystal, and not the difference in distance traveled due to the two waves leaving their respective planes at different angles. If we account for the latter difference in distance travelled, wouldn't the derivation be different?

Furthermore, in the derivations that I have seen, two parallel waves are shown leaving their respective planes. How can two waves that are parallel interfere if they never actually meet?


Overall, I'm just really confused about the derivation for Bragg's conditions, as it just seems incorrect to me. Could you please tell me what I'm misunderstanding or doing incorrectly?
Thank you so much.

First the law is better called Braggs law of reflection, so it does not talk of rays going through the crystal. Second it talks of a wave coming in one direction and so of cause all being reflected at the same angle. If you have refection at several plains, the interference is even better, same as with a two slit experiment and a grit. Your last concern: parallel rays meet at infinity, so the picture is not exact, but compared to the other distances the distance you detect the interference ist almost infinity. (you do the same in deriving interference of light on a slit or a grid,
